# KeyError: 'max_overlaps' on tensorflow ver Faster R-CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I tried to run python Faster-RCNN based on tensorflow, which clone from https://github.com/smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF

I built a dataset by myself and re-write data API to make dataset fit. The images in the dataset are all composed of meaningless background and text.
I got a .txt file to record the text location in a image, such as

```
ID_card/train/3.jpg 1 209 39 261 89
```

And my goal is to find text from a new image.
But when I run

```
python ./tools/train_net.py --device cpu --device_id 1 --solver VGG_CNN_M_1024 --weight ./data/pretrain_model/VGG_imagenet.npy --imdb ID_card_train --network IDcard_train
```

I got this KeyError: 'max_overlaps'
and here is the terminal record and error traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "./tools/train_net.py", line 97, in <module>
max_iters=args.max_iters)
  File"/Users/jay_fu/tasks/catpatch/ClickCatpatch/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 259, in train_net    
roidb = filter_roidb(roidb)
```

File"/Users/jay_fu/tasks/catpatch/ClickCatpatch/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 250, in filter_roidb
    filtered_roidb = [entry for entry in roidb if is_valid(entry)]
File"/Users/jay_fu/tasks/catpatch/ClickCatpatch/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/train.py", line 239, in is_valid

```
    overlaps = entry['max_overlaps']

KeyError: 'max_overlaps'
```

I did googled and tried to delete /cache folder, and it didn't work. Next time i run the code the folder and .pkl file would be created again and then the same error came out.
some other answer said delete another folder lib/datasets/VOCdevkit-matlab-wrapper
however smallcorgi/Faster-RCNN_TF do not contain this folder, so i have no way to go.

I wonder what happened to my code and what would cause this error. I have no idea about what to do.
Anyone can give me some help, solution or whatever a piece of idea?

edit:
I run the demo on @VegardKT  's idea, the demo works good.
terminal shows succeed and figure 1-5 shows up.

Comment: sorry for the bad format i dont know what happened to that. the traceback ends at **KeyError**, instead of  **(roibd)**

Comment: Have yoy tried running the demo that is included in the repo?

Comment: actually I havent run the demo, but i will try right now